# Security concern for Asp,net MVC app when invoking action method from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I have added the Authentication attribute on controller classes which are for admin purposes like adding, removing categories and product. All such controllers(ManageCategory, ManageProduct) are decorated with following :-

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

These controllers have *Upload* and *Remove* action methods which are invoked by jquery from the rendered view. Since client script don't use the URL or postback, I am bit skeptical if someone can bypass the controller authorization. These action methods are very sensitive because it provides the ability to remove a file on server. Following is the code from *Remove* action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Remove(string fileName)
{
    string completFileName = Server.MapPath("~" + fileName);
    System.IO.File.Delete(completFileName);
    return Json(true);
}
```

Though this action method resides in a Controller with Authorization, Can someone still reach it without logging-in. Should i be worried and do something else or one will always need to be authorized as administrator before accessing this ?.

Comment: That's a question of whether you trust ASP.NET MVC's `Authorize` construct for controllers. The answer is either "trust them" or go read their source

Comment: @Raynos I see you are an expert in javascript and jquery. Can you access this action method on my website via some script injection and delete a file ??

Comment: I don't know, I can certainly try, whether the `Remove` method would be invoked depends 100% on how `Authorize` works. So basically, if you don't trust it go confirm it works correctly by reading the source

Comment: I invoked the upload action method from another view after logging out and got the HTTP Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by..

> Since client script don't use the URL or postback

AJAX requests from client script send cookies just the same as regular page requests - have a look at the headers of an AJAX request using Firebug or Fiddler or some such tool.

This includes the .ASPXAUTH cookie which standard ASP.NET authentication uses. The controller will perform exactly the same authentication checks on an AJAX request as it would on a normal page request.

Answer (score 1):

Controller level attributes are applied to all actions in that controller, so `Upload()` and `Remove()` will behave as though they are decorated with:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```